# click and control issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello

I need advice

Hi, hello

I need advice on one issue

I want to add a control of the selected element (random element if a random element is selected to click on different elements)

code is

```
var souřadnice = [
  "Apples",
  "Bananas",
];



var randomsouřadnice = souřadnice[Math.floor(Math.random()*souřadnice.length)];

setTimeout(

    function() {
document.getElementById("coordinateTargetFirstTime").value = randomsouřadnice ; }, (Math.random() * 500) + 3000);
```

if i chose banana i would click on the clicker button

```
setTimeout (function () {document.querySelectorAll ("input [value = 'Clicked']") [0] .click ();}, (Math.random () * 1000) + 5000);
```

if I chose the second variant then the Clicked 2 button

```
setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Clicked2']")[0].click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 5000);
```

thanx for help :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question a bit more, are you looking for a way to tie a fruit to an action and then randomize the selection of fruit?

Comment: @ksankar  yes selection fruit ( selection fruit Banana ( click element clicked ) selection fruit apples ( click element clicked 2 )

Comment: setTimeout (function () {document.querySelectorAll ("input [value = 'Clicked']") [0] .click ();}, (Math.random () * 1000) + 5000);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **single random, yet different, choices** from an array then the best approach is to

- shuffle the array first and
- then pick the elements in a sequential order:

```js
const fruit = ["Apples","Bananas","Oranges","Mangos"],
      getFruit=i=>fruit[i];

function shuffle(a,n){ // shuffle array a in place (Fisher-Yates)
 console.log("shuffling");
 let m=a.length;
 n=n||m-1;
 for(let i=0,j;i<n;i++){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*(m-i)+i);
  if (j-i) [ a[i],a[j] ] = [ a[j],a[i] ]; // swap 2 array elements
 }; return a
}
      
shuffle(fruit);

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((b,i)=>{
 let txt=b.innerText;
 b.onclick=()=> txt=="shuffle"? shuffle(fruit) : console.log(txt+': '+getFruit(i));
})
```

```html
<button>fruit one</button>
<button>fruit two</button>
<button>shuffle</button>
```

I used a Fisher-Yates algorithm to shuffle the array in place.

And another comment: Even though JavaScript now allows you to use unicode characters in variable names I would strongly recommend to not use them and instead keep to ASCII characters. This will make collaboration on an international level (as we are practicing here!) easier.

**Note:**
In the onclick-handler for the two fruit buttons I used the function `getFruit()` instead of directly referencing `fruit[i]`. This makes sure that the "picking" will happen at the time of the click and not at the time when the handler function was defined!

Comment: ok and problem first choice click? 2 and 3  nod click

Comment: OK, I built two buttons and a third "shuffle" button for you to play with. The principle is still the same ...

Comment: the problem is that i can't work with the console log they need to make 2 elements
selected one that would be written to the console log

and then from the console log I would need to write the given element into the field once and then also when pressing both buttons to press the button for both elements, so there is a problem

I know how it can select an element problem is rather that I can not make the console log to click on that element and then according to the element press the button

Comment: It would help if you could share the HTML too (preferably in a snippet) and demonstrate with it, _which content_ you want _where_ and under _which conditions_. You should edit your original question for that.